# Power BI: How to make visualisation set Slicer value?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, slicers

I have a page in a Power BI file that has a few slicers that are synced to other pages.

Basically, I am trying to get a functionality where, if the user clicks on a slice of a pie chart, it sets that filter across all pages as opposed to just the other charts of the same page.

If I can set the chart to set the selections in the slicers, my needs will be met, as the slicers are synced.

Is there any way to do this or to meet my objective?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not yet. You can add the idea to the PBI team page (https://ideas.powerbi.com).